# what does this error mean and how to solve it "message":"Products \"%1\" and \"%2\" have the same set of attribute values.","parameters"

Tags: product, attributes, configurable-product, sku

I did an upload and the simple skus were created, but the configurable sku shows this error and is not created. What does it mean and how can I fix it?

[image]

Comment: Explain in details what you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the simple products that are linked up with that configurable do not contain unique attribute values. So if you have two child simple products attached to the configurable and they are using attribute color, for example one will need to be Blue and the other Red. This error will show if you have both simples set to Blue.

Comment: Thank you very much, you were right, I had two identical attributes in the simple skus, I made the correction and it was processed correctly